# AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret key are changing for each connection

Tags: quickbooks

I am using  "PHP v3 SDK for QBO". Each Time when we connect to Quickbook, The  AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret are changing. But In the _sample code provieded by PHP v3 SDK for QBO, we need to hardcode the AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret key. Each time  this values are changing, In Code we need to change these key otherwise code will not produce any result. Any permanent solution for this?

```
       $accessToken = '';
       $accessTokenSecret = '';
       $consumerKey = '';
       $consumerSecret = '';

       $requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(
       $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret, $consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each time this values are changing,

Why are the access token and access token secret changing?

The only way these can change is if *you* do something to change them (e.g. disconnect/connect, or a reconnect call).

What are you doing to change them, and why?

Comment: I am a beginner in quickbook & my doubt is about getting these keys (Access Token,Access Token Secret).In my online application, I clicked Test connect to app (OAuth). After connecting to my test app, I clicked the link "App Menu API Test". In this page I got all keys(Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Access Token Secret). Are you saying, user do not want to click & connect again. If so, there will no need to change the these keys(Access Token,Access Token Secret) in customer fecthing file in PHP SDK Sample. Please replay

Comment: Correct - they should connect ONCE. After that, you should be storing the keys so they don't need to connect again - just use the keys you already stored.